# jQuery trigger('change') method doesn't trigger checkbox functionality

Tags: jquery

I have a form with a conditional field which appears when you select a checkbox. I am using the jQuery trigger('change') method to preselect the checkbox when the page loads. The check box is correctly selected on page load but the conditional logic doesn't work unless you manually click the checkbox with the mouse.

The script is added to the bottom of the footer so is loaded last.

The site is using jQuery v3.5.1 with WordPress. The form fields and conditional logic are loaded via a WordPress plugin.

**Question:** Why doesn't the trigger('change') method load the functionality of the checkbox?

[image]

**JS:**

```
jQuery(window).on('load', function() {
   jQuery("#field_3_1").prop( "checked", true ).trigger('change');  
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="rednaoWooRow ">
<div class=" rnColumnContainer rnColumnField_3" style="height: auto; opacity: 1; display: inline-block; width: 100%; vertical-align: top;">
  <div class="rednaoWooColumn" style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; vertical-align: top;">
     <div style="margin-bottom: 5px;" class=" rnField_3 rncheckbox rednaoWooField ">
        <div class="rednaoControl">
           <div class="rnTextFieldInput ">
              <div class="rednaoLabel" style="font-weight: bold;"><label>morethan5</label></div>
              <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; width: 100%;">
<input name="field_3_1" id="field_3_1" type="checkbox" value="1"><label class="rnOptionItem" for="field_3_1" style="margin-left: 5px; cursor: pointer; display: inline-flex; align-items: center;"> morethan5</label></div>
           </div>
           <div>
              <div class="rootSwitchContainer " style="overflow: auto;">
                 <div style="position: static;">
                    <div style="height: auto; opacity: 1; overflow: auto; position: static; width: 100%;"></div>
                 </div>
              </div>
              <div class="rootSwitchContainer " style="overflow: auto;">
                 <div style="position: static;">
                    <div style="height: auto; opacity: 1; overflow: auto; position: static; width: 100%;"></div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

```
<div class="rednaoWooRow ">
<div class=" rnColumnContainer rnColumnField_1" style="height: auto; opacity: 1; display: inline-block; width: 100%; vertical-align: top;">
  <div class="rednaoWooColumn" style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; vertical-align: top;">
     <div style="margin-bottom: 5px;" class=" rnField_1 rncheckbox rednaoWooField ">
        <div class="rednaoControl">
           <div class="rnTextFieldInput bottom">
              <div class="rednaoLabel" style="font-weight: bold;"><label>Checkbox</label></div>
              <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; width: 100%;"><input name="field_1_1" id="field_1_1" type="checkbox" value="1"><label class="rnOptionItem" for="field_1_1" style="margin-left: 5px; cursor: pointer; display: inline-flex; align-items: center;"> Product option</label></div>
           </div>
           <div class="rnTextFieldQuantity bottom">
              <div class="rednaoLabel"><label style="font-weight: bold;">Quantity</label></div>
              <input class="rnInputQuantity" placeholder="" style="width: 100%;" type="number" value="0">
           </div>
           <div>
              <div class="rootSwitchContainer " style="overflow: auto;">
                 <div style="position: static;">
                    <div style="height: auto; opacity: 1; overflow: auto; position: static; width: 100%;"></div>
                 </div>
              </div>
              <div class="rootSwitchContainer " style="overflow: auto;">
                 <div style="position: static;">
                    <div style="height: auto; opacity: 1; overflow: auto; position: static; width: 100%;"></div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case if I were you I would use

```
jQuery(window).on('load', function() {
  jQuery("#field_3_1").trigger('click');  
});
```

this will trigger change and do exactly what you need

I would even add a setTimeOut() function so the visual effect would show up to user when everything else on the page is loaded

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, I just tried this with the timeout function but the results are the same, the checkbox is ticked but the conditional logic is not working. jQuery(window).on('load', function() {
 setTimeout(function() {
  jQuery("#field_3_1").trigger('click');  
 }, 5000);
});

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
Kindly find my pen to demonstrate my suggestion
https://codepen.io/MohamedTalaat333/pen/gOKxMEK

Comment: Thanks for demo, for some reason this is still not working for me, I've put up a live demo here: http://dynamicshift.co.uk/product/product

Comment: I investigated you demo,
- Looks like the input already has a click event that is preventing default behaviour called when you trigger your click.
- but in your case, I found another solution for this issue,
you need to trigger the change event on the input, you can do that by triggering click on the <label> element next to it.
I tried it from my side on your demo and it worked.
Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks so much Mohamed, triggering the click on the label instead worked perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: Most Welcome :)
Vote!